# Multiprocessing with a for loop that appends to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I've got a loop like this one:

```js
df = []
for i in range(50):
    if i <= 10:
        df.append(i)
    else:
        df.append(i+1000)
```

I'd like to run it with Multiprocessing, something like this (this does not work):

```js
df = []
items = range(50)
def try_my_operation(item):
    if i <= 10:
        df.append(i)
    else:
        df.append(i+1000)

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10)
futures = [executor.submit(try_my_operation, item) for item in items]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Can someone help me please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your **specific** question? See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Hi dspencer, I need to run the loop with parallel processing (the second block of code is just a draft that does not work). Thanks for the interest

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to execute your code using multiple processes could be to use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) to establish a pool of workers (according to the number of CPU cores available on your machine), then [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) your `items` to the function you want to call:

```
import multiprocessing as mp                                                    

def try_my_operation(i):                                                        
    if i <= 10:                                                                 
        return i                                                                
    else:                                                                       
        return i + 1000                                                         

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                      
    items = range(50)                                                           
    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:                                          
        df = pool.map(try_my_operation, items)                                  
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 1031, 1032, 1033, 1034, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1038, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1049]
```

Note that I have changed the function to return the value, rather than append to a global list in order to avoid the complexity of sharing state between the parallel processes.